# How do i get Data Flow Task's error details in user defined variables and pass it to stored procedure as input parameters?

Tags: ssis, bids

I have a Data Flow task i want to get the error details in variables I defined and then I wanna pass these variables to a stored procedure as input parameters.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What version of SSIS? If 2016 then https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2015/11/27/error-column-improvements-for-ssis-data-flow-updated-for-rc2/

Comment: @GregGalloway BIDS 2008